# Techniques to solve complicated simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I want to solve 5 equations simultaneously for 5 variables (N2[t],TT[t],PP'[t],SS'[t],z1'[t], code attached at the end of the post).

The equations are extremely long and complicated. I have tried using both `NSolve` and `FindRoot`. `NSolve` takes forever to run while 'FindRoot' gives me imaginary solutions, and the solutions vary greatly when I make minor adjustments to the starting values.

For example, `FindRoot[eqnlist, {{TT[t], 1}, {N2[t], 1}, {SS'[t], 10}, {PP'[t] ,  10}, {z'[t], 0.5} }]` gives me `{TT[t] -> 0.841069 - 1.21403*10^-12 I,  N2[t] -> 0.00465752 + 0.00174916 I,  Derivative[1][SS][t] -> 0.000664034 - 33.0891 I,  Derivative[1][PP][t] -> -0.000975051 + 49.6336 I,  Derivative[1][z][t] -> -6.27545*10^-6 - 1.62921*10^-6 I}`

while changing to `{z'[t], 0.4}` gives me `{TT[t] -> 0.841069 + 1.16717*10^-12 I,  N2[t] -> -5.3095*10^-6 - 0.0000693473 I,  Derivative[1][SS][t] -> -8.66276*10^-6 - 33.0891 I,  Derivative[1][PP][t] -> 0.0000129935 + 49.6337 I,  Derivative[1][z][t] -> 4.72639*10^-9 + 6.44207*10^-9 I}`

Is there any efficient and reliable way to solve such complicated simultaneous equations to obtain all the real solutions? Thank you.

P.S. After staring at the equations for a while, equation 1, 2 and 4 only depend on 3 variables while equation 3 and 5 depend on all 5 variables.

Equations: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aGpOQuZ9jDdzX9dUTMTtQYMfE0f5ySEKAqslnT5g5R8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mixture of exact numbers and real numbers with several digits like `0.05886` in `eqnlist`, therefore we can't use `WorkingPrecision` higher then `$MachinePrecision` as an option in `FindRoot`. To solve this problem we can use  `NMinimize`. First, remove all `==` from `eqnlist` with

```
eq = Table[
   eqnlist[[i]][[1]] - eqnlist[[i]][[2]], {i, Length[eqnlist]}];
```

and use it as follows

```
sol = 
 NMinimize[eq . Conjugate[eq], {TT[t], N2[t], SS'[t], PP'[t], z'[t]}, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5]

Out[]= {1.356*10^-6, {TT[t] -> 0.841065, N2[t] -> 24.7031, 
  Derivative[1][SS][t] -> -0.0946177, 
  Derivative[1][PP][t] -> -0.015582, 
  Derivative[1][z][t] -> -0.000194137}}
```

Second, use `sol` with `FindRoot` in the form

```
 sol1 = 
 FindRoot[Table[eq[[i]] Conjugate[eq[[i]]] == 0, {i, Length[eq]}], 
  Table[{var[[i]], var[[i]] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, Length[var]}], 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 6]

Out[]= {TT[t] -> 0.841069, N2[t] -> 24.5294, 
 Derivative[1][SS][t] -> -0.00237493, 
 Derivative[1][PP][t] -> -0.000395797, 
 Derivative[1][z][t] -> -4.92941*10^-6}
```

Let check that `eq` been solved with maximal error of $2.37\times 10^{-5}$

```
Table[eq [[i]], {i, 5}] /. sol1

Out[]= {-4.92942*10^-6, -0.0000237491, -0.000010477, \
-4.13951*10^-9, -1.76118*10^-6}
```

Hence the value `z'[t]` needs to be recalculated. We can plot `eq` as function of `z'[t]` as

```
Plot[Log[eq . Conjugate[eq] /. Drop[sol1, -1]], {z'[t], -10^-4, 0}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

The minimal value of  `eq . Conjugate[eq]` is about $10^{-21}$ it is why we can't  solve this problem with `$MachinePrecision` using `FindRoot`. Now we can try

```
sol2=NMinimize[{Log[eq . Conjugate[eq] /. Drop[sol1, -1]], 
  z'[t] < 0}, z'[t]]

Out[]= {-21.0926, {Derivative[1][z][t] -> -2.95916*10^-6}}
```

Let check how we improve solution

```
Table[eq [[i]], {i, 5}] /. Join[Drop[sol1, -1], sol2[[2]]]

Out[]= {-2.95917*10^-6, -0.0000237491, -0.0000104769, \
-4.13951*10^-9, -2.93993*10^-6}
```

Compare to that find above with `sol1` we improve first and last equations. We can recommend turn all numbers to rational and use option `WorkingPrecision -> 40` with `sol1` as starting point in `FindRoot` as follows

```
eq1 = Rationalize[eq, 10^-30];

 sol3 = 
 FindRoot[Table[eq1[[i]] Conjugate[eq1[[i]]] == 0, {i, Length[eq1]}], 
  Table[{var[[i]], var[[i]] /. sol1}, {i, Length[var]}], 
  AccuracyGoal -> 18, PrecisionGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000]

During evaluation of In[63]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 10000 iterations.

Out[63]= {TT[t] -> 0.8410686705679302557765250318264307467021, 
 N2[t] -> 24.52500016238743443940870727557720488810, 
 Derivative[1][SS][
   t] -> -8.834618704174150338967041790049095324767*10^-8, 
 Derivative[1][PP][
   t] -> -1.472436452169582384601225318143779829260*10^-8, 
 Derivative[1][z][
   t] -> -1.833168600179621480183988024023755387758*10^-10}
```

This solution not converges but we can check that `eq1` satisfies with maximal error of $8.83\times 10^{-10}$

```
eq1 /. sol3

Out[]= {-1.833168600179621480*10^-10, \
-8.8346187050584847358310728019304536898*10^-10, -3.8972984275*10^-10,
  0.*10^-21, 2.83945093*10^-11}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "removing the '=='"? If the equal signs are removed, how does mathematic solve the equations?

Comment: @bobthelegend Actually we remove `==` to use `NMinimize` with `eq . Conjugate[eq]` then we use this solution as initial point for  `FindRoot` with `Table[eq[[i]] Conjugate[eq[[i]]] == 0, {i, Length[eq]}]` to compute real roots.

Comment: May I know how `eq` looks like? For example the equation in `eqnlist` may look like `a==b`, so after you remove the "==", it will just be `ab`?

Comment: @bobthelegend It looks as `a-b`  then we can use it  as `(a-b)^2`  for minimization or as equation `a-b==0` as well.

Comment: We can remove `==` with `eq = Table[
   eqnlist[[i]][[1]] - eqnlist[[i]][[2]], {i, Length[eqnlist]}];`. This line has been added to my answer.

Comment: I see, thank you so much

Comment: @bobthelegend You are welcome!